# Cron job causes 504

Tags: cron, cron-job

The cron job on my site us using up many resources and ultimately causing a 504 error.

I tested not passing a site key or passing the wrong site key and it ran succesfully with the error that the key is invalid.  When I place a the valid Key, it runs for the time set for response time and then I get a 504 error.  This sudendly stoped working.  Not sure what might have caused this, but for a long time it worked seamlessly and one day it started happening, but I cannot pinpoint what happened arround that time, and I can definetely say it was not an upgrade.  I have upgrated to the latest version since.

Can anyone help me with this issue, I am having to run the jobs manually from the scheduled tasks.

I  tried disableling all the tasks to see if one in particular was causing the issue, however the problem is still happening. I also increased the server response time to 240 and it is still sending the 504 error.

Would really appreciate some light as it is making me spend precious time in trying to figure out this issue.

Thank you much for any help and or guidance.

Jennifer

Comment: Can you try running with a different method like `cv`? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#choosing-a-method

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will give this a try